# How do I read uint32_t values out of a nested PROGMEM array?

Tags: c++, arduino

I have an array of 16x16 matrices of uint32_t values: `const uint32_t sprites[][16][16] PROGMEM = { ... };` I'm trying to read out the values with `pgm_read_dword(sprites + (submode * 256 + row * 16 + column) * sizeof(uint32_t))`, but am getting turned around and confused about how the address math works. In this, `submode` maps to the matrix index. `submode`, `row`, and `column` are all declared as `uint8_t`, in case it helps at all.

How do I correctly calculate the address for `pgm_read_dword`?

Is `pgm_read_dword` even how I want to try to read out `uint32_t` values? I'm immediately passing the output to a method that expects that type.

Comment: Why not simply `sprites[submode][row][column]`?

Comment: "_getting turned around and confused about how the address math works_" - Arrays are stored in [row-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order) in C++.

Comment: `pgm_read_dword(&sprites[submode][row][column]);` to second dude

Comment: @datafiddler Wow. That was it!? All of the PROGMEM examples made it seem way more complicated, like I couldn't just reference the element and then dereference. If you don't mind elaborating that into a full answer, I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: I just added a few characters to dude's comments. Answering your own question is appreciated here. You didn't elaborate the question itself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to datafiddler in the comments, it's as simple as just calling `pgm_read_dword(&sprites[submode][row][column])` and letting the compiler handle the offset calculations.